# Determine whether the set is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So I have a final tomorrow and I have no clue how to determine whether a set is vector space or not. I've looked online on how to do these proofs but I still don't understand how to do them. Can any one help me with a question like this?

Let V be the set of all positive real numbers. Determine whether V is a vector space with the operations below.

$x + y = xy$

$cx=x^c$

If it is, verify each vector space axiom; if not, state all vector space axioms that fail.

Edit: Turns out I'm going to fail the exam based on what you guys are saying.

Comment: Hint: it is a vector space. Which one of the axioms are you having difficulty with?

Comment: It helps if you write the (alleged) vector space operations as something else than $+$ and juxtaposition, so you won't get confused about what is really addition/multiplication and what is the vector space operation. So, say, define $\oplus \colon V^2 \to V$ by $x \oplus y := xy$ and scalar multiplication $\otimes \colon {\mathbb R} \times V \to V$ by $c \otimes x := x^c$.

Comment: @JustinCampbell Perhaps if you could show me how to do it with Closure under addition [(u+v) is in V] I may be able to do all of them.

Comment: @Mark, that appears to be a wholly different problem.  The OP is closed under $+$ because the product of two positive real numbers is a positive real number.

Comment: @vadim123 I don't understand.

Comment: @vadim123: sometimes in textbooks closure under the operation is listed as one of the axioms for e.g. a group.

Comment: @Mark: The "addition" you have defined on $V$ is just multiplication of positive real numbers. As vadim123 points out, since the product of two positive real numbers is positive, your vector space $V$ is closed under "addition."

Comment: I'm putting "addition" in scare quotes because I suspect your confusion arises from the fact that it is not the usual addition of real numbers, but rather (strangely) the product. Magdiragdag's suggestion is a good way to alleviate this confusion.

Comment: @JustinCampbell in a sense yes, but I still don't understand Magdiradag's response other than just use different notation.

Comment: That's all he's saying. Now do you not understand the statement "the product of two positive real numbers is positive" or do you not understand why this implies closure of $V$ under the addition you defined?

Comment: I don't understand the latter.

Comment: Stare at the definition of $V$ and its "addition." I don't know what else to say.

Comment: I just don't understand how to do these axioms. Some of them I can do now. But for example, can you explain how this works for the additive identity, or additive inverse?

Comment: @JustinCampbell thanks for trying to explain it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a start.

- Additive axioms:  For every $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R^+}$,

i) $x+y=xy = yx = y+x\, $ ( since real numbers commute)

ii) $(x+y)+z=xy+z = xyz = x+yz= x + (y+z).$

Can you continue?

Comment: I'm starting to get it now. But what about $x+0 = x$? That doesn't quite workout because wouldn't it be $(0)x= x^0 = 1$?

Comment: Am I missing something here?

Comment: $0 \not\in V$; the neutral element with respect to the 'addition' on $V$ is $1$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Can you show me how to do the additive identity?

Comment: Expand $x + 1$ (or, rather $x \oplus 1$, using my notation). What does that give?

Comment: Where do you get $x + 1$ from?

Comment: It really, really helps if you explicitly write out the axioms you want to prove and don't mix up the usual operations (and elements) of $V$ with the vector space operations. For instance, to address the confusion with the additive identity, $V$ has to have a neutral element with respect to $\oplus$. Neutral elements to addition are commonly called $0$, *but $0$ is not the neutral element with respect to addition here*, so better call it something else, e.g. $z$ (until you realize it's actually $1$).

Comment: @Magdiradag This doesn't help. If you look at my first comment underneath the answer, you can see I am trying to to prove $x+0 = 0$. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: I like Mhenni Benghorbal's response because it's simple. I'm trying to understand what you're saying but I only learn well by examples.

Comment: @Magdirabg:  I believe the OP just started learning about vector spaces and he should wok the axioms out so he can have some feeling for them. On the other hand, your answer is a little bit advance him.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal how does this work for the additive identity? Everyone here gave up.

Comment: The axiom is talking about the zero *vector*, which is not necessarily the zero that is in $\mathbb{R}$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the zero vector is $(0, 0) \ne 0$. In your case, the zero vector is $1$, because $x \oplus 1 = x1 = x = 1x = 1 \oplus x$.

Comment: @Mark: good job. I am happy that you understood it. Keep working hard.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal do you have any advice on what's the best approach on doing well in math courses? I do many problems but they all seem so unique that its quite difficult to understand how the concepts are related to each other.

Answer (score 3):

Choose another notation $x \oplus y := xy$ and $c \otimes x := x^c$. Then the exponential map gives an isomorphism of structures $(\mathbb{R},+,*) \cong (\mathbb{R}^+,\oplus,\otimes)$. Since the first is a vector space, the same is true for the latter. And this way the creator of this "exercise" came up with this artificial vector space (he wanted that you waste your time with computations ...).

Comment: It's not the fact, that I have to do all the axioms. It's that I should know how to do them. I really don't know how to do any of the axioms really.

Comment: You haven't read my answer carefully. Anyway, you *should* have an idea how to prove $x \oplus (y \oplus z) = (x \oplus y) \oplus z$.

Comment: If you really want to do it the hard way: just write the axioms down (using $\oplus$ and $\otimes$) and then expand the definition (of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I still don't understand the easy way.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: this is a nice argument but I don't think the OP will understand it in time for his exam tomorrow.

Comment: I think the OP will understand nothing because he doesn't make any effort to think. No offense, but this is my observation.

Comment: @MartinBradenburg I was trying to understand the best I could. And  I always give as much effort as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You need to translate the usual vector space axioms, expressed using '+' and '$\cdot$', into your problem's notation. For example, the vector space axiom $$c\cdot(x+y)=c\cdot x+c\cdot y$$becomes$$(xy)^c=(x^c)(y^c)$$
As other comments have indicated, the closure axioms need to be dealt with. If $x,y\in V$, then you need to show that $xy$ is in $V$, since $xy$ is the 'vector sum' of $x$ and $y$.

One last point: do you know about vector space isomorphisms? There is an isomorphism between your vector space and a much more familiar vector space (call it $W$). If $\psi:V\rightarrow W$ stands for this isomorphism, then we have $$\psi(xy)=\psi(x)+\psi(y)$$for example.

By the way, you didn't not explicitly state what possible values $c$ could have.

Comment: I was never taught anything about vector space isomorphisms in my linear algebra course. The reason I didn't state the possible values of  $c$ is because that question is literally in my textbook so its not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky I got the same question in one of my Assignments. And here's what I got:

http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/linear_algebra/chpt3.pdf

The same question in here!

Hope it helped :)

Comment: While that link may answer the question, it's better to include the main ideas here, as the content could become inaccessible later.

Answer (score -3):

What about closure under scalar multiplication? For example, if c = 1/2 and x = -1, we have:  1/2*(-1) = (-1)^(1/2) which is not real. So, it's not closed under scalar multiplication, correct? Therefore, not a vector space.

Comment: Note than in the OP $V$ is the set of all positive real numbers.