# Is a set of measures a vector space?

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces

I would like to know, is it possible that a set of measures can be viewed as a vector space over field $\mathbb{R}$? If yes, under what condition it is a vector space? How to define addition and scalar multiplication?

For example, suppose that $\Omega$ is a finite set. Is $\Delta(\Omega)$ (set of all probability measures on $\Omega$) a vector space? How about $\Delta(\Delta\Omega)$?

If anyone has any clue, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So, there are actually two different questions asked.

---

No, measures do not form a vector space (as already pointed out), but they form a [module over a rig with scalar multiplication given by Lebesgue integration of measurable nonnegative functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903250/rig-module-of-measures-with-scalar-multiplication-given-by-lebesgue-integrat).

Also, more simply: they form a module over the rig of nonnegative reals in the obvious way.

---

However the story for *probability* measures is a bit different.

The right structure to put on the set of probability measures is arguably that of a [convex space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convex+space) as opposed to a module or vector space structure. This is because $\Delta(\Omega)$ is a convex subset of the $\mathbb R$-vector space of all signed measures on $\Omega$.

The reason my previous answer doesn't work is of course that given $\mu,\nu\in \Delta(\Omega)$ we have $(\mu + \nu)(\Omega) = 2 \neq 1$, so certainly $\Delta(\Omega)$  is not closed under $+$; nor is it closed under scalar multiplication since $c\mu (\Omega) = 1$ if and only, if $c = 1$.

One way around these issues is talking about *convex combinations* of probability measures instead, hence the need for convex spaces.

Convex spaces have been rediscovered many times and never quite became famous enough to be well-known. The [paper by Fritz](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5522) is a good introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot be viewed as a vector space since a measure has to be positive. So if $\mu$ is a non zero measure, you cannot define $-\mu$.

Comment: Let's hope the poster isn't interested in [signed measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure)

Comment: But positive reals can be viewed as a vector space.

Comment: @Yi-HsuanLin Under what operations? Are you adding with real addition? If so, the positive reals do not form an Abelian group...

Comment: @rschwieb
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676767/determine-whether-the-set-is-a-vector-space

Answer (score 1):

Any set can be made into a vector space if you're allowed to define addition and multiplication any way you want.  On the other hand the usual addition of measures is obviously not closed for probability measures.  The space of signed measures is a vector space with many useful subspaces (smooth functions etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't learned signed measure before. Could you suggest me any reference? note...paper...textbook...etc